# Changing style of button in RadInput

Tags: button, coding-style, telerik

Hi I have a scenario where I need to change the image of the button in Radinput control based on some criteria.

I have the following styles defined
   .MyButton
   {
     background:url('Error.png') 0 0 no-repeat !important;
   }

.MyButton_1
   {
     background:url('SupportsNotes.png') 0 0 no-repeat !important;
    background-color:Red !important
   }

And my control is

Now if I enter some value that is out of range or in case of dates if the date is future date I want to change the image in the button to 'SupportsNotes.png' from MyButton_1 CSS class. I am unable to find any method to set the css class for the button dynamically.

I want to do this in javascript. Can you please help me on this?

Thanks.

Regards,
Ramya

Comment: Sorry, your control is.... what? Can you change < and > to &gt; and &lt;?

Comment: The control is  &lt;telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox1" runat="server"  Skin="Outlook"  ShowButton="true" ButtonCssClass="MyButton" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="1" ButtonsPosition="Right" ShowSpinButtons="true" Type="Percent"  MinValue="20" MaxValue="100" AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="false" Width="100px" &gt

Answer (score 1):

Take a look... Everything explaind very well at: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

Thank You. I tried out a few solutions and found one. Am posting it here. May be someone might need this

### Radtextbox control

<telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox4" runat="server" Skin="Outlook" ShowButton="true"
            ButtonCssClass="MyButton" TextMode="MultiLine" Label="1.2 Name" AccessKey="N"
            AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="true" ClientEvents-OnBlur="test"><telerik:RadTextBox>

test is the method called on Blur

Psuedocode for test method is

1. get the radcontrol RadTextBox4.
2. Check the required conditons for eg:
   if (txtbox.get_value() != '') {
   txtbox.Button.className = "MyButton";
   }
3. Assign button class dynamically based on the value in the textbox.

In the above function,If regex is not matched we assign invalid button image, If regex is matched we assign a correct button image if there is error we assign error image from the cssclass

.MyButton
        {
            background: url('Error.png') 0 0 no-repeat !important;
        }
        .MyButton_1
        {
            background: url('help_16x16.png') 0 0 no-repeat !important;
        }
        .MyButton_2
        {
            background: url('RegexError.png') 0 0 no-repeat !important;
        }

So the above code can be used to change images and styles of button in radtextbox dynamically